# C++ allocation standard?

Tags: c++

Let's assume I have a class Foo, and a function Bar

```
void Bar(void)
{
Foo a();
}
```

Does that mean that a will necessarely be NOT allocated in the main memory ?
Or does this depend on compilers so the compiler may allocate memory and result in the same thing as if we wrote `Foo* a=new Foo`

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Main memory". C++ implementations i know always use RAM, unless you use some microcontrollers with non-uniform RAM or GPGPU, maybe. `a` object will be located on stack.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo a();` is a function declaration. It should be `Foo a`; And `a` is in the memory of stack.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is an *automatic variable*. This means that the object contained in that variable is guaranteed to be destroyed at the end of the scope *automatically*.

When you use `new`, the object is destroyed only when you `delete` it explicitly (or by explicitly using a mechanism that takes care of destroying it, like smart pointers). In other words, the lifetime is *manually* managed.

Of course, automatic lifetime semantics are not the same as manual semantics under any circumstance. That being said, the storage location (stack, heap, registers, or something else) in both cases is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if `a` fits in a register, it could end up using "no memory" at all. Otherwise, it will be allocated on the stack, in what I would call "main memory", same kind of memory as with `Foo *a = new Foo;`, but a different portion [`new` uses heap memory, the stack is not same as heap, but same KIND of memory].

Of course, if the class `Foo` contains a constructor, it could in itself call `new` and all manner of other functions that may or may not alter the usage of memory...